# Multiple rows with forms to save in CakePHP

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, save, inline

I am currently working on a bidding system, and I'm stuck on saving the winning bid numbers and amounts. This is cakePHP 2.4 by the way. When I go to submit a bid after editing the values it will (depending on the solutions) create a new record with no information, or just refresh and do nothing. I've tried a couple different ways of adding the id to the forms, and that doesn't seem to help (that was the most common error).

I feel like I'm really missing something, and I'm still fairly new to cake so I'm not sure what it is.

Whats going on in the view: I have a paginated for each spitting out rows for my tables. Each row looks like this

```
<tr>
  <td><a href="/kBid/bids/assign/2001">2001</a> </td>
  <td>Wee love basket </td>
  <form action="/kBid/bids" id="BidIndexForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/></div>
  <td><div class="input number"><input name="data[Bid][winningBidder]" value="0" type="number" id="BidWinningBidder"/></div> </td>
  <td><div class="input number"><input name="data[Bid][winningAmount]" value="0" type="number" id="BidWinningAmount"/></div> </td>
  <td>
  <input type="hidden" name="data[Bid][id]" value="2001" id="BidId"/><button class="button" style="color: #FFF;" type="submit">Save</button>                </td>
</tr>
```

And my controller to save/view the items:

```
public function index($id = null) {
    if ($this->request->is('post')){
        $this->Bid->id = $this->request->data['Bid']['id'];
        if($this->Bid->save($this->request->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash('Bid assigned!');
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    }

    $this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;
    $this->Bid->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('bids', $this->paginate());
}
```

I have tried for about 2 hours now a lot of "solutions" and none of them have worked so far. Is it an issue with multiple forms on one page? Each of them when I view the source have separate ID's so as long as those are being passed I don't see the issue.

As well as I am trying to dump the sql at the end of the view but it's only giving me the sql that it used to select the rows for displaying.

Really appreciate any advice or if there is a different way I should be doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your code carefully. A glance at your codes. :

- Your form tag is not closed. (Use Form helper to create form instead of hardcoding the html)

Comment: Thank you for seeing that! When I was working with the form elements and displaying them,`$this->Form->end();` Was not within the loop. I really appreciate the help and now this is working and can be done with that fix.